# What are the permissions AdMob requires in android

Tags: android, location, admob, ads

On [Google’s site](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/) they only mention two of them:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Nothing about location? Is it ok?

I noticed  on forums that people also use other permissions, like:

```
<meta-data android:value="true" android:name="ADMOB_ALLOW_LOCATION_FOR_ADS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />     
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
```

Is it ok to use only those two first, or shall I extend my list to location (anything else?) in order to serve better profiled ads?

Answer (score 2):

If you enable these permissions then this allows admob to geo-target your ads.

Of course, the only reason to declare:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
```

is because you want to try out different locations during development. You don't need this permission when your app is released.

Comment: Thanks, one more question. Do I need to call from my code request.setLocation(location); to set the location for the ad or will it happen automatically just when the permission is set in manifest file.

Comment: Is it too late to rejoin the party? I just saw your question. You need to call request.setLocation(location); as you noted. Here's a reference from AdMob: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/intermediate

Answer (score 2):

it may help someone

```
You should never request location permissions from users for the sole purpose of advertising.
```

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6373176?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

this way you will get ads from the area(country) where the device is located