# Unity3D - How to remove plugins that contain location permission request?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, plugins

Recently, I want to update my games on Google PlayStore. Before updating the APK, I need to submit information about age range on the **app content** menu.

Regarding my games, the audience is **children under 13**, so I get messages below:

> You must remove the request for location permissions from your app if
>   your target audience only includes children under 13

The problem is I don't know how to remove and which plugins that make the permission request on Unity3D.

[image: This]

Any ideas?

Also, there's one more problem related to this but I'm in doubt whether or not to include my other questions with this question. I will open a new question later.

Comment: After exporting your project into Android Studio you can search for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION in Android Manifest files and then delete them

Comment: You just want to know which plugin might be asking for location permission without having to export it to android studio, right?

Comment: Yes, it right @DeekshithHegde

Comment: Search for AndroidManifest file in the project folder and you will see few of them. Check in which manifest file the location permission is used and once you find that file look for the folder in which it is or looking for the name in the manifest file might help too. Doing this you will get a fair idea of which plugin might be using the location permission

Answer (score 1):

To figure out which plugin is asking the permission you could just do a process of elimination. Make an empty scene and add one of your plugins at a time, and check when the location permission prompt shows up.

Besides doing such a brute force you can also go to the documentation pages of whatever plugins you are using, and see if any of them mention requiring location permission. If one does, you'll know its that one, and will probably also include documentation on how to turn it off (if available), or have some sort of contact form to ask the developer if it can be turned off.

As Temre mentioned in the comments you can also export your project and search for `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` in the manifest files.

You will have to try these methods for yourself though, we can't "just" point out a plugin that'd cause this since we don't know the project and every plugin.

That said I think some top candidates to look into would be (going from your screenshot):

- Facebook SDK: if you use the [graph.api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/location/) it needs permission for the `graph.api.location`
- Google mobile ads: This requires location permission to server geo-targeted adds. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752769/what-are-the-permissions-admob-requires-in-android) about its permissions

Once you have pinned down which plugin is asking for the permission check to see if there is an option to turn it off, or remove the asking code yourself if you have the source code.

If neither of those are an option you'll probably have to look for an alternative plugin/write your own solution. Or edit the manifest file by deleting the `ACCES_FINE_LOCATION` as mentioned before in the comments.

Comment: is there any unity plugin to block certain permission?

Answer (score 0):

Find `AndroidManifest` in your project and delete or comment this line

```
<uses-permission> android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<uses-permission> android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Check out this official [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-manifest.html) of unity for android manifest.

Also Check for `Input.location` in your script and remove that code. It will generate manifest.